# NotificationCenter in another class does not call selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want put common functions together to avoid redundant code(in this case, make keyboard up with UIResponder). I tried to pass viewController so that the another class can access to the viewController instance. The notification was called but both @objc functions didn't called. How should I do?

- ViewController

```
class ViewController {

      let addedFunc = bringFunc()
      override func viewDidLoad() {

        addedFunc.upWithKeyboard(VC: self)
      }
```

- class

```
class bringFunc {


    var view: UIView!
    func upWithKeyboard(VC: UIViewController) {

        view = VC.view
        let bringinstance = bringFunc()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(bringinstance, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(bringinstance, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    }

    @objc  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

        guard let rect = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
         let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(rect.size.height/1.5))
            self.view.transform = transform

        }

     }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        guard let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            self.view.transform = transform

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance:

```
let addedFunc = bringFunc()
```

And this is another instance:

```
let bringinstance = bringFunc()
```

So the notifications are being sent to the wrong instance. Not only that: the instance to which they are being sent is gone by the time the notifications arrive. Your code goes like this:

```
    // instance comes into existence:
    let bringinstance = bringFunc()

    // notification center is pointed at that instance:
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(bringinstance, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(bringinstance, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    // function comes to an end! `bringInstance` is destroyed, kaboom...
    // and now there is nothing for the notification center to talk to
```

Comment: Why  ```bringinstance``` is destroyed? Although it created in same closure.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by any of those words. The structure is `func upWithKeyboard(VC: UIViewController) { let bringinstance = bringFunc() }`. So `bringinstance` is purely local to the curly braces. When we reach the right curly brace, it is destroyed. You don't seem to know about classes-and-instances _or_ scope. You need start right at the beginning.